# android view getWidth() returns 0 even in onPreDraw()

Tags: android, text, size, width, android-viewtreeobserver

Based on answers in SOF, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

I have tried to measure the view late enough (`onPreDraw`) unlike the question opener in the above question link.

I have this code:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = myAccountView.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
    new OnPreDrawListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onPreDraw() {

        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
          viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        }

        int measuredWidth = myAccountView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int width = myAccountView.getWidth();

        return true;
      }
    });
```

}

nevertheless, `measuredWidth` and `width` are always 0

how can i get the view's width in pixels?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)

Comment: I have tried to measure the view late enough (onPreDraw) unlike the question opener in the above question link.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you add the OnPreDrawListener somewhere in an RecyclerView.Apadter or something similar?

`onPreDraw` will be called multiple times if you don't remove the listener directly. Therefore, wait until your View has a positive width and then remove the OnPreDrawListener.

```
@Override
public boolean onPreDraw() {
      if (myAccountView.getWidth() < 1) {
          // imageView might not be drawn yet
      } else {
         viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
      
         // you can do all your calculation here
      }

      return true;
}
```